# Meet a strange phenomenon of JavaScript Array.indexOf (in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, indexof, parseint

When I try to solve [ProjectEuler No.27](https://projecteuler.net/problem=27), I met a strange problem of JavaScript Array.indexOf (in Node.js).
The code is like below:

```
var primes = require('./primes1000.js');
var bigPrimes = require('./primes50000.js');
var maxNumber = 2;
var maxPair = {};

var getQuadratic = function(b) {
    var i = 0;
    var a = 0;
    while (Math.abs(a) < 1000) {
        var prime = primes[i];
        var a = prime - 1 - b;
        var length = getMaxNumber(a, b) - 1;
        if (length > maxNumber) {
            maxNumber = length;
            maxPair = {
                a: a,
                b: b
            };
            console.log(maxPair, maxNumber);
        }
        i++;
    }
};

var getMaxNumber = function(a, b) {
    var isPrime = true;
    var n = 1;
    while (isPrime) {
        n = n + 1;
        var result = (n + a) * n + b;

        isPrime = (bigPrimes.indexOf(result) !== -1);
        // if ((a === 1) & (b === 41)) {
        //     console.log(result, isPrime);
        // }
    }

    return n;
};

for (var i = 0; i < primes.length; i++) {
    getQuadratic(primes[i]);
}
```

primes1000.js and primes50000.js is written like this:

```
module.exports = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,...,997];
module.exports = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,...,611953];
```

The problem occurs at

```
bigPrimes.indexOf(result)
```

When result = 47, the indexOf method returns -1, which means not found.

After a lot debugging and testing, at last I changed the node to

```
bigPrimes.indexOf(parseInt(result))
```

Then it works.

But the result of

```
typeof result
```

and

```
typeof bigPrimes[14]
```

are both "number"
And

```
parseInt(result) === result
```

returns true.

I didn't see why I have to parseInt to get the correct return value of indexOf.

Answer (score 1):

Your result could be a float for some reason. JavaScript has only one Number class. It's not a good language for multiplying, dividing. But I guess it's not a bad thing to cast it to an Int. I don't think there's a very specific reason why this happens.